# Configuring 2 javascript sliders on 1 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I know only CSS and little to no Javascript so I need some help here. I have 2 [pikachoose](http://pikachoose.com) sliders:

```
$(document).ready(
      function (){
          $("#pikame").PikaChoose();
          $("#pikame2").PikaChoose();
});
```

Both are autosliding as is set in javascript:

```
(function ($) {
     var defaults = {
        autoPlay: true,
        speed: 5000,
```

How can I set `#pikame2` to stop autoslide? I guess I have to set autoplay false or speed to 100k, but I don't know how to specifiy that it would only do that to the 2nd slider. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the options in each call of the plugin, like this:

```
$("#pikame").PikaChoose({autoPlay:true});
$("#pikame2").PikaChoose({autoPlay:false});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#pikame2").PikaChoose ({autoplay: false})
```

You can pass options into each init call.